# Android: actionbarsherlock 4.2 options menu and google maps v2 lag

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, google-maps-android-api-2, android-support-library, fragmentpageradapter

## Setup

I have run into a very weird lag bug. Using ABS 4.2, support library v4 revision 11, the new SupportMapFragment and nested fragments as well. This bug appears on both nexus 4 on Android 4.2 and nexus one on 2.3.6.

I have these fragments:

#1 "MainContainer" with a viewpager containing a fragmentpageradapter.

#2 "SupportMapFragment" within this fragmentpageradapter. I extended SupportMapFragment but the same bug applies to the default implementation of it.

#3 One extra fragment (just adjusting settings with preferences so nothing special)

## Did:

1. Had fragment #2 running and clicked an options menu item (in the overflow menu) which runs the fragmenttransaction to fragment #3. This adds the old fragment MainContainer to backstack.
2. Clicked back button which pops #3 and puts the #1 (MainContainer) and #2 (SupportMapFragment) into showing again.

## Expected:

A smooth running maps fragment.

## Happened:

The mapview is very slow and hardly functions. I can't see any other lag throughout the app.

## The weird part:

The lag persists like this despite any fragment transactions I do throughout any life cycle changes except if the activity is recreated or fragment is destroy:ed (MainContainer is always in the fragmentmanager). BUT the map suddenly runs smoothly if I press the overflow button to see the actual button I pressed in step 1 (just showing the items in the overflow menu that is).

Logically this shows something is changed by just showing the items in the overflow menu that changes. Since there is so much code involved in all these components and I can't really find anything that is out of the ordinary, except using the SupportMapFragment inside another fragment (getChildFragmentManager() ), it is probably better if you ask for what piece of code could be of interest and I update with it.

Please help because I'm going crazy...

Comment: try following link for possible fix:
[enter link description here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21702720/232727