# Android App Perfomance Issues on JellyBean

Tags: android, performance

I am working on a project where we are creating an Android app that requests data from a server to be displayed on the user's device (not sure how much more background information I can give... will try my best if more is needed). We are supporting from Gingerbread (2.3) and upwards (up to latest JellyBean 4.2).

Now the odd thing is that the app runs very fast and smoothly on phones that are running 2.3.x (these are in general, slightly older devices such as LG Optimus 2X), while if we try and run the app on relatively newer devices (Galaxy s3 etc.) that have JellyBean 4.1+, the app runs so slow that the performance becomes a usability issue. This occurs on screens that pulls data from the servers and displays them.

I have also confirmed this behaviour by running it on the emulator.

So I did some research based on the fact that we get the following in LogCat for only 4.1+:

> 06-29 23:11:17.796: I/Choreographer(691): Skipped X frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

So it seems like this thing called Choreographer was added for API lvl 16, and it coordinates timing of animations, inputs and drawings.

I'm wondering if this is causing this issue? Seems unlikely to be a hardware issue, our app doesn't have any animations and we do not have separate implementations for 2.3.x and 4.1+

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing your network requests in AsyncTasks? Starting with ICS, AsyncTask are serialized instead of parallelized. See this [article](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html) by CommonsWare for more information

Comment: We are using AsyncTask for all our network requests

Comment: Thanks for that, will go and discuss this with the others and will report back

Comment: I ran into some network performance issues a while back for a client and did some digging and found out that the android team has started to discourage usage of apache http client and instead use HttpURLConnection.  I'm not sure if you are using that or not but it made a huge difference for me! http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Comment: "I'm wondering if this is causing this issue?" -- no. Use Traceview to determine where you are spending your time, and enable `StrictMode` in your debug builds to more quickly find out about obvious issues (e.g., disk I/O on the main application thread).

Comment: Hi guys, so it seems nicopico => CommonsWare's article pretty much explains what the problem is. We do in fact call a number of AsyncTasks for requests one after another for various Activities of our app, and that causes the slowdowns for later versions of Android (I just went and tested it). Thank you all very much for your help, now we need to have a quick discussion of whether we will be having concurrency problems within our app if we take CommonsWare's suggested fix.

Comment: By the way... how can I set this question as answered? Since you guys all just made comments, I can't mark any of it as answers... Should I just answer it myself and then mark it as answered? (That seems like i'll be taking credit for it...)

Comment: I will change my comment to an answer, if that is good with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with Ice Cream Sandwich, the default behavior of `AsyncTask` has changed from a parallelized executor to a serialized one.

As you are executing several network requests in a batch of `AsyncTask` (as seen in comment), that means your application waits for the previous request response before lauching the next one.

You can change the executor of an `AsyncTask` using this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
else {
    myTask.execute();
}
```

Source: [AsyncTask Threading Regression Confirmed](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html) from CommonsWare blog.

Answer (score 1):

I has experienced the same thing on Kindle Fire, Sony Xperia Z and Samsung S4 (all with android 4.2).

The fix is: at App Manifest file remove "android:supportsRtl="true"".

Hope it will save your time. I spend 4 hours on tests and merging before i got it.